# matplotlib normed histograms

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I'm trying to draw part of a histogram using matplotlib.

Instead of drawing the whole histogram which has a lot of outliers and large values I want to focus on just a small part. The original histogram looks like this:

```
hist(data, bins=arange(data.min(), data.max(), 1000), normed=1, cumulative=False)
plt.ylabel("PDF")
```

[image]

And after focusing it looks like this:

```
hist(data, bins=arange(0, 121, 1), normed=1, cumulative=False)
plt.ylabel("PDF")
```

[image]

Notice that the last bin is stretched and worst of all the Y ticks are scaled so that the sum is exactly 1 (so points out of the current range are not taken into account at all)

I know that I can achieve what I want by drawing the histogram over the whole possible range and then restricting the axis to the part I'm interested in, but it wastes a lot of time calculating bins that I won't use/see anyway.

```
hist(btsd-40, bins=arange(btsd.min(), btsd.max(), 1), normed=1, cumulative=False)
axis([0,120,0,0.0025])
```

[image]

Is there a fast and easy way to draw just the focused region but still get the Y scale correct?

Comment: How would the normed values be calculated without taking the whole set of data into account? In general, the histogram values should be calculated so that the integral of the curve is 1, not simply by dividing by the number of points.

Comment: In the absence of a function describing the distribution the best you can do is count the number of points and divide accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to plot a subset of the histogram, I don't think you can get around to calculating the whole histogram.

Have you tried computing the histogram with `numpy.histogram` and then plotting a region using `pylab.plot` or something? I.e.

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

data = np.random.normal(size=10000)*10000

plt.figure(0)
plt.hist(data, bins=np.arange(data.min(), data.max(), 1000))

plt.figure(1)
hist1 = np.histogram(data, bins=np.arange(data.min(), data.max(), 1000))
plt.bar(hist1[1][:-1], hist1[0], width=1000)

plt.figure(2)
hist2 = np.histogram(data, bins=np.arange(data.min(), data.max(), 200))
mask = (hist2[1][:-1] < 20000) * (hist2[1][:-1] > 0)
plt.bar(hist2[1][mask], hist2[0][mask], width=200)
```

**Original histogram:**
[image: Original histogram]

**Histogram calculated manually:**
[image: Histogram calculated manually]

**Histogram calculated manually, cropped:**
[image: Histogram calculated manually, cropped]
(N.B.: values are smaller because bins are narrower)

Answer (score 5):

I think, you can normalize your data using a given weight. (`repeat` is a numpy function).

`hist(data, bins=arange(0, 121, 1), weights=repeat(1.0/len(data), len(data)))`